# How to wrap a proper generator function around a SAX Parser

Tags: python, sax

I've got 35.5Mb .XLSM file.  When the actual usable content is expanded, it swamps DOM parsers like element tree exhausting memory after a long, long running time.

When using a SAX parser, however, the `ContentHandler` seems to be constrained to accumulate rows in a temporary file.  Which is a little irritating because the parser and the main application *could* have a simple co-routine relationship where each row parsed by SAX could be yielded to the application.

It doesn't look like the following is possible.

```
def gen_rows_from_xlsx( someFile ):
    myHandler= HandlerForXLSX()
    p= xml.sax.makeParser()
    p.setContentHandler( myHandler, some_kind_of_buffer )
    for row in some_kind_of_buffer.rows():
        p.parse() # Just enough to get to the ContentHandler's "buffer.put()"
        yield row
```

Periodically, the `HandlerForXLSX` would invoke `some_kind_of_buffer.put( row )` to put a row into the buffer.  This single row should be yielded through `some_kind_of_buffer.rows()`.

A simple coroutine relationship between a SAX parser and `gen_rows_from_xslx()` would be ideal.

Have I overlooked some generator-function magic that will allow me to package SAX as a coroutine of some kind?

Is the only alternative to create a SAX parsing thread and use a `Queue` to get the rows built by the parser?

Or is it simpler to bite the bullet and create a temporary file in the SAX parser and then yield those objects through the generator?

Related: [Lazy SAX XML parser with stop/resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059455/lazy-sax-xml-parser-with-stop-resume).

Comment: A couple of typos in this, no? (1) s/makeParser/make_parser/ http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.reader.html#module-xml.sax.xmlreader (2) setContentHandler takes only One argument http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.reader.html It looks like you wrote about this problem a month ago: http://slott-softwarearchitect.blogspot.com/2010/10/xlsm-and-xlsx-files-finally-reaching.html What went wrong?

Comment: @hughdbrown. (1) Correct.  A subclass, however, could have an extra argument.  (2) Correct.  That creates a temporary file, which I'm unhappy with.

Comment: David Beazley has an example (http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/index.html) (cosax.py) of how to push SAX events through a coroutine target. Is that close to what you are looking for?

Comment: @unutbu: It might be what I'm looking for.  I think the `.send()` may be the piece of generator-fu I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"""I've got 35.5Mb .XLSM file. When the actual usable content is expanded, it swamps DOM parsers like element tree exhausting memory after a long, long running time."""

I don't understand this. Things you should be using:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

ET.iterparse(sourcefile) # sourcefile being a cStringIO.StringIO instance holding your worksheet XML document

element.clear() # leave only scorched earth behind you
```

[This article](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm) shows how to use `iterparse` and `clear`.

Example: Loading an XLSX (100Mb, most of which is two worksheets each with about 16K rows and about 200 cols) into the xlrd object model:

Elapsed time about 4 minutes [beat-up old laptop [2 GHz single-core] running Windows XP and Python 2.7]. Incremental memory usage maxes out at about 300Mb of memory, most of which is the output, not the element tree.

Comment: If only the application small enough that it would work.  Sigh.  Sadly, it's a Django site, so there's quite a bit going on.  I can certainly try cElementTree.  However, the entire DOM seems needless in the case where the XML is a serialized database and row-at-a-time processing is all that's happening.  Keeping memory use down makes all the web site users happier.

Comment: @S.Lott: Yeah, so you don't collect the whole tree (if that's what you mean by "the entire DOM"): you use **ITER**parse and when you have finished with each row, you do row_element.clear() to blow away all of the row's child (cell) elements.

Comment: How does iterparse know to iter on the specific XML structures I care about?  From your answer, it's not clear how to use iterparse to watch an event and a relevant tag.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could use the `IncrementalParser` interface for this? Something like:

```
def gen_rows_from_xlsx(someFile):
    buf = collections.deque()
    myHandler = HandlerForXLSX(buf)
    p = xml.sax.make_parser()
    p.setContentHandler(myHandler)
    with open(someFile) as f:
        while True:
            d = f.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            if not d: break
            p.feed(d)
            while buf: yield buf.popleft()
    p.close()
```

To do this with `parse`, you would have to `yield` across multiple stack frames, something which Python simply does not support.